# How to use REGEX patterns to return day of the week if a date is entered?

Tags: regex, master-data-services, master-data-management

I am trying to create something that will populate the day of the week in one cell based on a date entered in another, BUT in Master Data Services.  I know I will need to do this in a business rule and apply it to the attributes.  I am wondering if this can be don using REGEX patterns or any other clever method.  So, for example if I have a column with 12/21/2016 in it, I want the next column to say "Wednesday".   Thanks!

Comment: Regex really isn't the right tool for this job. You need a date/calendar library that can tell you that "12/21/2016" is a Wednesday. Many such libraries exist on various platforms, but I'm not familiar at all with whether they exist in the system you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be using sql and use a calculated column or directly in a view. I'm not that familiar with MDS so there might be a better solution (or not even possible).

```
alter table mytable add weekday as DATENAME(dw,fieldname) persisted
```

Do never try to do your own date/time functions, [you will fail](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)